# How to convert NSScanner from objective c to c++?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have to convert objective c to objective c++.

I stuck with the following function in SVGParser.

```
   -(float) pathNextFloat
   {
        NSAssert( pathIndex < [pathString length], @"SVNParser: path parse error");
        unsigned int stringLen = [pathString length];
        const char *str = [pathString UTF8String];

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCString:&str[pathIndex] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
        float ret = 0;
        BOOL ok = [scanner scanFloat:&ret];
        NSAssert(ok, @"SVG parser: path error parsing float");
        // find next comma
        for( ; pathIndex < stringLen ; pathIndex++ ) {
            if( str[pathIndex] == ',' ) {
                pathIndex++;
                break;
             }
        }
        return ret;
     }
```

I have difficult to find solution for UTF8String, NSScanner, scannerwithstring, stringwithcstring.

Can any one assist me?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can compile this code as Objective-C++. So you mean you want to convert it to C++?

Comment: @kazukiSakamoto: yes.

Comment: look into sscanf and/or find a c++ svg parser